# Error in File Transfer Activity says -"File not found matching the pattern" even though file is available

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, ftp

I have setup an automation in Automation studio.
The 1st activity is : **Data Extract**
[image: image of data extract activity]

2nd activity is **File Transfer**
[image: image of file transfer]

After i run this File Transfer Activity I get an error like this :[image: error image]

But in FTP the file is added[image: FTP image]

I am stuck and every-time i run this automation I get this error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone pls guide

Comment: your FTA is moving a file from the safehouse to an FTP folder. If you can FTP in and see a file its not in the safehouse and thus the FTA would fail

Comment: thanks, but how to fix this issue

Comment: If the file is already in the FTP, then the file transfer is unnecessary. You can then just access it at the location it already exists (assuming the extract folder?).